# Multiply collection and randomly merge with other - Apache Spark

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark

I am given two collections(RDDs). Let's say and a number of samples

```
val v = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b", "c"))
val a = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

val samplesCount = 2
```

I want to create two collections(samples) consisting of pairs where one value is from the 'v' and second one from 'a'. Each collection must consist all values from v and random values from 'a'.

Example result would be:

```
(
 (("a", 3), ("b", 5), ("c", 1)), 
 (("a", 4), ("b", 2), ("c", 5))
)
```

One more to add is that the values from v or a can't repeat within a sample.

I can't think of any good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You randomly shuffle the RDD to be sampled and then join the two RDDs by line index:

```
def shuffle[A: reflect.ClassTag](a: RDD[A]): RDD[A] = {
  val randomized = a.map(util.Random.nextInt -> _)
  randomized.sortByKey().values
}

def joinLines[A: reflect.ClassTag, B](a: RDD[A], b: RDD[B]): RDD[(A, B)] = {
  val aNumbered = a.zipWithIndex.map { case (x, i) => (i, x) }
  val bNumbered = b.zipWithIndex.map { case (x, i) => (i, x) }
  aNumbered.join(bNumbered).values
}

val v = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b", "c"))
val a = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val sampled = joinLines(v, shuffle(a))
```

RDDs are immutable, so you don't need to "multiply" anything. If you want multiple samples just do:

```
val sampledRDDs: Seq[RDD[(String, Int)]] =
  (1 to samplesCount).map(_ => joinLines(v, shuffle(a)))
```

Comment: Just one more question.. What is the meaning of `reflect.ClassTag`?

Comment: Some Spark methods need to know the class of `X` when operating on an `RDD[X]`. If you remove the ClassTags the compiler will tell you what needed them :). See also http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html#using-a-context-bound-of-a-type-parameter for this syntax for an unnamed implicit parameter.